# perl error after activestate uninstall cygssp-o.dll

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl, activestate

After uninstalling ActiveState I've been getting this weird error when trying to execute "perl" from the command prompt.

> The program can't start because cygssp-o.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

After uninstalling ActiveState, I tried to install Strawberry Perl, I've even cleaned my SYSTEM path to only include Strawberry Perl.

However, this message still comes up when I try to execute the following command

> perl

The only way to fix it is to reinstall ActiveState.

Any idea what's wrong? I tried to search that error and it doesn't seem to be very popular.

Comment: By the way, ActivePerl is the perl distribution. ActiveState is the company behind ActivePerl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that `perl` is looking for `cygssp-o.dll`  means you must have a [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) `perl` somewhere on your path.

You can examine your path, and remove references to Cygwin or just move the Strawberry Perl `bin` directory ahead of it.